# I want to import the json file only if they don't exist

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongo 3.4
I want to import json file from json array to mongod using bash script, and I want to import the json file only if they don't exist. I tried with --upsert but it does not work.
Is there any easy way to do it? Thanks

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json --jsonArray --upsert
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoimport -d dbName -c collectionName jsonFile.json -vvvvv
```

Even though the output of mongoimport says that n of objects were imported, the exsiting document with same data has not been overwritten.

if use --upsert it will update the existing document.

Found similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018580/how-to-import-only-non-existing-documents)